# Akka Streams - Backpressure for Source.unfoldAsync

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm currently trying to read a paginated HTTP resource. Each page is a Multipart Document and the response for the page include a `next` link in the headers if there is a page with more content. An automated parser can then start at the oldest page and then read page by page using the headers to construct the request for the next page.

I'm using Akka Streams and Akka Http for the implementation, because my goal is to create a streaming solution. I came up with this (I will include only the relevant parts of the code here, feel free to have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/L7R7/46615daa6d1a41d0499c261db8a2f3bb) for the whole code):

```
def read(request: HttpRequest): Source[HttpResponse, _] =
  Source.unfoldAsync[Option[HttpRequest], HttpResponse](Some(request))(Crawl.crawl)

val parse: Flow[HttpResponse, General.BodyPart, _] = Flow[HttpResponse]
  .flatMapConcat(r => Source.fromFuture(Unmarshal(r).to[Multipart.General]))
  .flatMapConcat(_.parts)

....

def crawl(reqOption: Option[HttpRequest]): Future[Option[(Option[HttpRequest], HttpResponse)]] = reqOption match {
  case Some(req) =>
    Http().singleRequest(req).map { response =>
      if (response.status.isFailure()) Some((None, response))
      else nextRequest(response, HttpMethods.GET)
    }
  case None => Future.successful(None)
}
```

So the general idea is to use `Source.unfoldAsync` to crawl through the pages and to do the HTTP requests (The idea and implementation are very close to what's described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39458276/5247502). This will create a `Source[HttpResponse, _]` that can then be consumed (Unmarshal to Multipart, split up into the individual parts, ...).

My problem now is that the consumption of the `HttpResponse`s might take a while (Unmarshalling takes some time if the pages are large, maybe there will be some database requests at the end to persist some data, ...). So I would like the `Source.unfoldAsync` to backpressure if the downstream is slower. By default, the next HTTP request will be started as soon as the previous one finished.

So my question is: Is there some way to make `Source.unfoldAsync` backpressure on a slow downstream? If not, is there an alternative that makes backpressuring possible?

I can imagine a solution that makes use of the Host-Level Client-Side API that akka-http provides, as described [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/host-level.html#using-the-host-level-api-in-a-streaming-fashion) together with a cyclic graph where the response of first request will be used as input to generate the second request, but I haven't tried that yet and I'm not sure if this could work or not.

---

**EDIT:** After some days of playing around and reading the docs and some blogs, I'm not sure if I was on the right track with my assumption that the backpressure behavior of `Source.unfoldAsync` is the root cause. To add some more observations:

- When the stream is started, I see several requests going out. This is no problem in the first place, as long as the resulting `HttpResponse` is consumed in a timely fashion (see [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html) for a description)
- If I don't change the default `response-entity-subscription-timeout`, I will run into the following error (I stripped out the URLs):
  `[WARN] [03/30/2019 13:44:58.984] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16] [default/Pool(shared->http://....)] [1 (WaitingForResponseEntitySubscription)] Response entity was not subscribed after 1 seconds. Make sure to read the response entity body or call discardBytes() on it. GET ... Empty -> 200 OK Chunked`
  This leads to an `IllegalStateException` that terminates the stream: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Substream Source cannot be materialized more than once`
- I observed that the unmarshalling of the response is the slowest part in the stream, which might make sense because the response body is a Multipart document and thereby relatively large. However, I would expect this part of the stream to signal less demand to the upstream (which is the `Source.unfoldAsync` part in my case). This should lead to the fact that less requests are made.
- Some googling lead me to [a discussion about an issue that seems to describe a similar problem](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/1836). They also discuss the problems that occur when a response is not processed fast enough. The [associated merge request](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/pull/2270/) will bring documentation changes that propose to completely consume the `HttpResponse` before continuing with the stream. In the discussion to the issue there are also doubts about [whether or not it's a good idea to combine Akka Http with Akka Streams](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/1836#issuecomment-434388819). So maybe I would have to change the implementation to directly do the unmarshalling inside the function that's being called by `unfoldAsync`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. As I already mentioned in the edit of my question, I found [this comment](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/1836#issuecomment-434388819) to an issue in Akka HTTP, where the author says:

> ...it is simply not best practice to mix Akka http into a larger processing stream. Instead, you need a boundary around the Akka http parts of the stream that ensures they always consume their response before allowing the outer processing stream to proceed.

So I went ahead and tried it: Instead of doing the HTTP request and the unmarshalling in different stages of the stream, I directly unmarshal the response by `flatMap`ing the `Future[HttpResponse]` into a `Future[Multipart.General]`. This makes sure that the `HttpResponse` is directly consumed and avoids the `Response entity was not subscribed after 1 second` errors. The `crawl` function looks slightly different now, because it has to return the unmarshalled `Multipart.General` object (for further processing) as well as the original `HttpResponse` (to be able to construct the next request out of the headers):

```
def crawl(reqOption: Option[HttpRequest])(implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem, materializer: Materializer, executionContext: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[(Option[HttpRequest], (HttpResponse, Multipart.General))]] = {
  reqOption match {
    case Some(request) =>
      Http().singleRequest(request)
        .flatMap(response => Unmarshal(response).to[Multipart.General].map(multipart => (response, multipart)))
        .map {
          case tuple@(response, multipart) =>
            if (response.status.isFailure()) Some((None, tuple))
            else nextRequest(response, HttpMethods.GET).map { case (req, res) => (req, (res, multipart)) }
        }
    case None => Future.successful(None)
  }
}
```

The rest of the code has to change because of that. I created [another gist](https://gist.github.com/L7R7/2601a71300dbd4700d3eda5acdad048e) that contains equivalent code like the gist from the original question.

I was expecting the two Akka projects to integrate better (the docs don't mention this limitation at the moment, and instead the HTTP API seems to encourage the user to use Akka HTTP and Akka Streams together), so this feels a bit like a workaround, but it solves my problem for now. I still have to figure out some other problems I encounter when integrating this part into my larger use case, but this is not part of this question here.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [implementation](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/2a9fa71a3a7c08e3e78fa8197c08edb790448ea7/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/impl/Unfold.scala) of the `Source.unfoldAsync` the passed in function is only called when the source is pulled:

```scala
def onPull(): Unit = f(state).onComplete(asyncHandler)(akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts.sameThreadExecutionContext)
```

So if the downstream is not pulling (backpressuring) the function passed in to the source is not called.

In your gist you use `runForeach` (which is the same as `runWith(Sink.foreach)`) that pulls the upstream as soon as the `println` is finished. So it is hard to notice backpressure here.

Try changing your example to `runWith(Sink.queue)` which will give you an `SinkQueueWithCancel` as the materialized value. Then, unless you call `pull` on the queue, the stream will be backpressured and will not issue requests.

Note that there could be one or more initial requests until the backpressure propagates through all of the stream.

Comment: I observed that the part of the stream that does the unmarshalling of the HTTP response takes quite some time. This part sits in between the HTTP call itself and the Sink with the println. Shouldn't this cause the upstream to slow down? If so, this would overrule the fast Sink. I also tried to add a `.buffer` after the HTTP requests, but that didn't make any difference

Comment: Yes, it should. Maybe `flatMapConcat` is misbehaving here. Try changing it to `.mapAsync(1)(r => Unmarshal(r).to[Multipart.General])`

Comment: Thanks, good point. I think `mapAsync` is what I want here anyways instead of `flatMapConcat` with `Source.fromFuture` inside. I just tried it, but it doesn't make any difference. However, I found some other interesting things that might be of interest. I'll update my question to share what I learned.