# Excetption thrown while executing Akka Streams doesn't contain any references to the source code

Tags: scala, akka-stream

There is an akka streams scala application, it consumes messages from kafka topics, converts them to Dynamo DB requests, and executes them. Sometimes the app throws exceptions these exceptions:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Response entity was not subscribed after 1 second. Make sure to read the response `entity` body or call `entity.discardBytes()` on it -- in case you deal with `HttpResponse`, use the shortcut `response.discardEntityBytes()`. POST / Default(104 bytes) -> 200 OK Default(13512 bytes)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.CompletableFutureUtils.errorAsCompletionException(CompletableFutureUtils.java:65)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.lambda$execute$0(AsyncExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:930)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:907)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.CompletableFutureUtils.lambda$forwardExceptionTo$0(CompletableFutureUtils.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeAttemptExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:103)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeRetryExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:184)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.lambda$attemptExecute$1(AsyncRetryableStage.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.CompletableFutureUtils.lambda$forwardExceptionTo$0(CompletableFutureUtils.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.lambda$null$0(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:103)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.completeResponseFuture(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:240)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.lambda$executeHttpRequest$3(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:930)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:907)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Response entity was not subscribed after 1 second. Make sure to read the response `entity` body or call `entity.discardBytes()` on it -- in case you deal with `HttpResponse`, use the shortcut `response.discardEntityBytes()`. POST / Default(104 bytes) -> 200 OK Default(13512 bytes)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:111)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException.create(SdkClientException.java:47)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:223)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:218)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeRetryExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:182)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Response entity was not subscribed after 1 second. Make sure to read the response `entity` body or call `entity.discardBytes()` on it -- in case you deal with `HttpResponse`, use the shortcut `response.discardEntityBytes()`. POST / Default(104 bytes) -> 200 OK Default(13512 bytes)
    at akka.http.impl.engine.client.pool.SlotState$WaitingForResponseEntitySubscription.onTimeout(SlotState.scala:313)
    at akka.http.impl.engine.client.pool.NewHostConnectionPool$HostConnectionPoolStage$$anon$1$Event$.$anonfun$onTimeout$1(NewHostConnectionPool.scala:187)
    at akka.http.impl.engine.client.pool.NewHostConnectionPool$HostConnectionPoolStage$$anon$1$Event$.$anonfun$event0$1(NewHostConnectionPool.scala:189)
    at akka.http.impl.engine.client.pool.NewHostConnectionPool$HostConnectionPoolStage$$anon$1$Slot.runOneTransition$1(NewHostConnectionPool.scala:277)
    at akka.http.impl.engine.client.pool.NewHostConnectionPool$HostConnectionPoolStage$$anon$1$Slot.loop$1(NewHostConnectionPool.scala:364)
    at akka.http.impl.engine.client.pool.NewHostConnectionPool$HostConnectionPoolStage$$anon$1$Slot.updateState(NewHostConnectionPool.scala:373)
    at akka.http.impl.engine.client.pool.NewHostConnectionPool$HostConnectionPoolStage$$anon$1$Slot.updateState(NewHostConnectionPool.scala:267)
    at akka.http.impl.engine.client.pool.NewHostConnectionPool$HostConnectionPoolStage$$anon$1$Slot.$anonfun$updateState$2(NewHostConnectionPool.scala:289)
    at akka.http.impl.engine.client.pool.NewHostConnectionPool$HostConnectionPoolStage$$anon$1.$anonfun$safeCallback$1(NewHostConnectionPool.scala:616)
    at akka.http.impl.engine.client.pool.NewHostConnectionPool$HostConnectionPoolStage$$anon$1.$anonfun$safeCallback$1$adapted(NewHostConnectionPool.scala:616)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.runAsyncInput(GraphInterpreter.scala:467)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:517)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:625)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:800)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:818)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:716)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java. base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

The stack trace only leads back to the libraries method calls, but not to the actual application source code, any ideas on where to search for the actual cause of the error or how to setup akka to properly report the exception?

Here is roughly the code that makes requests to the dynamo DB:

```
  def makeRequest[In <: DynamoDbRequest, Out <: DynamoDbResponse](
      client: DynamoDbAsyncClient,
      retries: DynamoDBRetries,
      request: In
  )(implicit
      dbOp: DynamoDbOp[In, Out],
      system: ActorSystem
  ): Future[Out] = {
    implicit val implicitClient: DynamoDbAsyncClient = client
    val source = RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff(
      RestartSettings(retries.minBackoff, retries.maxBackoff, retries.randomFactor)
    ) { () =>
      Source.single(request).via(DynamoDb.flow(1)).map(Success.apply).recover {
        // some error handling
      }
    }
    source.map(_.get).runWith(Sink.head)
  }
```

and here is the code that chains the calls to the DDB:

```
    makeRequest(
      client,
      config.retries,
      req
    ).flatMap { result => makeRequest(
      client,
      config.retries,
      anotherRequest
    ) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is your code doing, but based on [Implications of the streaming nature of Request/Response Entities - Integrating with Akka Streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html#integrating-with-akka-streams), sounds like you are trying to consume http responses without handling the entity.

> This error indicates that the http response has been available for too long without being consumed.

The workaround could be

> It can be partially worked around by increasing the subscription timeout, but you will still run the risk of running into network level timeouts and could still exceed the timeout under load

```
akka.http.host-connection-pool.response-entity-subscription-timeout = 10.seconds
```

The suggested solution is implement the handling of the entity

```scala
implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
implicit val dispatcher: ExecutionContext = system.dispatcher

case class ExamplePerson(name: String)

def parse(line: ByteString): Option[ExamplePerson] =
  line.utf8String.split(" ").headOption.map(ExamplePerson.apply)

val requests: Source[HttpRequest, NotUsed] = Source
  .fromIterator(() =>
    Range(0, 10).map(i => HttpRequest(uri = Uri(s"https://localhost/people/$i"))).iterator
  )

val processorFlow: Flow[Option[ExamplePerson], Int, NotUsed] =
  Flow[Option[ExamplePerson]].map(_.map(_.name.length).getOrElse(0))

// Run and completely consume a single akka http request
def runRequest(req: HttpRequest): Future[Option[ExamplePerson]] =
  Http()
    .singleRequest(req)
    .flatMap { response =>
      response.entity.dataBytes
        .runReduce(_ ++ _)
        .map(parse)
    }

// Run each akka http flow to completion, then continue processing. You'll want to tune the `parallelism`
// parameter to mapAsync -- higher values will create more cpu and memory load which may or may not positively
// impact performance.
requests
  .mapAsync(2)(runRequest)
  .via(processorFlow)
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

---

For more info:

- [akka http - issue 1836 - Substream Source cannot be materialized more than once when reading from s3](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/1836)
- [Akka HTTP Error Response entity was not subscribed after 1 second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62053942/akka-http-error-response-entity-was-not-subscribed-after-1-second)

Comment: yeah, thank you, I also found similar recommendations on the internet, but the problem is, first, the app doesn't use akka http, at least not directly, and second, in order to add the code I first need to find out where does the error happen - because the exception doesn't have any clues.

Comment: The stacktrace shared shows a `SdkClientException` that comes from aws sdk. You said that you have an **akka stream app** that **consumes** from **kafka** and **publish** in **DynamoDB**. My guess is that you are using [Alpakka - DynamoDB](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/dynamodb.html) which depends on `akka-http` and `aws sdk dynamodb`. If you inspect the `DefaultDynamoDbClient` you will see that is doing http requests there. If that is not the case, I would need more context to help you

Comment: How would you add logging here? 
`Source.single(request).via(DynamoDb.flow(1)).runWith(Sink.head)`? And do you see a problem there? I would also update the question

Comment: In the example from the docs, the requests can be parallelized with a `mapAsync` and then the request transformed with `response.entity.dataBytes.runReduce(_ ++ _).map(parse)`. In your case looks like you need to chain many http requests and one depends on the provious one. I would say it's a design problem what you have. [Chain Akka-http-client requests in a Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39437718/chain-akka-http-client-requests-in-a-stream) might help you

Comment: What is the problem with the design? Also, one depends on the other only in the sense that if the first one fails the second one shouldn't be sent. Wouldn't just having 2 mapAsync work?

Comment: [mapAsync](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mapAsync.html) lets you process things concurrently and returns a future that keeps the order of the elements processed. Doing that could create backpressure. Maybe [mapAsyncUnordered](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mapAsyncUnordered.html) is better if the order doesn't matter. Remember that [Akka Streams operators](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-parallelism.html) (Flows and Sources) are “fused” together and executed sequentially by default.

Comment: Using `mapAsync` will let you process things concurrently. Then you have the [chained http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39437718/chain-akka-http-client-requests-in-a-stream) that can be processed using [unfoldAsync](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/unfoldAsync.html). Not sure how easy is to implement all that things together. Maybe you can create different steps that can work isolated and use some message queue in the middle to avoid backpressure